View and edit "source code" (not as WYSIWYG) of a DOCX or ODT file
I'm slowly getting more used to how styles work in Microsoft Word's DOCX and OpenOffice/LibreOffice Writer's ODT file formats. I like how they can be used to keep content and styles separate, like can be done with HTML+CSS or LaTeX. I don't like how I can only find WYSIWYG and menu-based ways to edit these documents.
Is there any non-WYSIWYG way to view and edit these files, where the styles applied to different parts of the text are visible as separate entities, instead of as the actual formatting of the text? Closer to a "source code" view like I would have using HTML+CSS or LaTeX.
I'm aware these files are essentially ZIP files of XML files, which can be extracted and edited manually, but is there any software that makes editing convenient?

I used to edit these XML files a lot, but always manually, I am not aware of any dedicated tool for this.

I have the same question, and I just found this post and got no result currently...
So I turn to search in all sites, and found this answer:
css applied to microsoft word
Hope to be of some help.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
